# Inequality with second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a question. We have $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\;f''(x)=0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and take a point $x_0$. Take a function $g(x)$ for which the second derivative exists. Assume $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and $f(x)>g(x)$ for each $x\not=x_0$ . Prove that $g''(x_0)\le 0$.

I tried to prove it using Jensen's inequality, but I don't have any idea. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What *exactly* do you neqn by $f''(x) = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, it shoul be $f:R->R$.

Comment: So you mean "$f''(x) = 0$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$"?

Comment: Yes. for each..

Comment: But you still have $\mathbb R^n$ in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $h = f - g$. Then $h(x_0)=0$, $h(x)>0$ for $x \neq x_0$, and $h''(x_0)=-g''(x_0)$.

Suppose $h''(x_0) < 0$. By Taylor's theorem, 
$$
h(x)=h(x_0) + h'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{h''(x_0)(x - x_0)^2}{2} + o(|x-x_0|^2).
$$

It follows that
$$
\frac{h(x)}{(x - x_0)^2} < \frac{h'(x_0)}{x - x_0} + \frac{o(|x-x_0|^2)}{(x - x_0)^2}.
$$
if $h'(x_0) \neq 0$, and

$$
\frac{h(x)}{(x - x_0)^2} = \frac{h''(x_0)}{2} + \frac{o(|x-x_0|^2)}{(x - x_0)^2}.
$$
if $ h'(x_0) = 0 $.

In either case, we can achieve $h(x)<0$ for $x$ close enough of $x_0$.
Therefore, we must have $h''(x_0)=-g''(x_0) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

First, show that $f'(x_0)-g'(x_0)=0,$ which you can show by invoking the limit definition of a derivative for the function $f-g$ and noting that $(f-g)(x_0)=0$ by assumption. You get $f'(x_0)-g'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{(f-g)(x)}{x-x_0}$. Taking the right hand limit shows this value must be greater than or equal to 0, while taking the left hand limit shows it must be less than or equal to 0 (given that $f\geq g$).

Next, note that since $f''(x)=0$, $f'(x)=k$ is a constant. Invoke the limit definition of a derivative on $(f-g)'$ to get the second derivative, which will simplify to $(f-g)''(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{k-g'(x)}{x-x_0}.$ Since $f''(x_0)=0$, we need only show that $(f-g)''(x_0)\geq 0$.

If we suppose for contradiction that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{k-g'(x)}{x-x_0}<0$ it follows that in a neighborhood $(x_0,x_0+h)$ we have $g'(x)>k$. But then $$g(x_0+h)=g(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}g'(x)>f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}k=f(x_0+h)$$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and basic integral inequalities. This is a contradiction. Thus, $(f-g)''(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{k-g'(x)}{x-x_0}\geq0,$ and we are done.